# oracle binary data types

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

is there a type or way how to store data in oracle in binary level.
I'm interested both in operations for dml at table and pl/sql.

Currently all binary elements are stored as varchar2(1000)='11111...0000.1111' however operations and data storage size is rather big, therefore need some solutions for optimization. If this data could be stored in binary format, it would require 1000/8 bytes
(have >700mln records)

Maybe a solution would be using some kind of java+oracle combination for these operations.

Ideas and suggestions welcome.

Comment: If you want binary operations (bitand, etc) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125055/oracle-type-casting/6127701#6127701

Comment: Oracle datatype `RAW` is the way to go. I've used this datatype in the past to store and process 4-byte (32-bit) as well 16-byte (128-bit) values. See Vincent Malgrat's answer, I'll not post an answer reiterating what he says.  You can play some games with the `NUMBER` datatype, but it has limits and turns out to be way more cumbersome.  The `BLOB` datatype gives you the advantage of being longer, but again, it is more cumbersome. The `RAW` datatype is really the way to go.

Comment: @spencer7593, only now I see your comments. Using `HEXTORAW` is the best solution. If you'll add an answer saying that OP should first convert the '10101010' strings to a hex string and then use hextoraw to insert them into a raw datatype - I'll upvote it. It doesn't use the problematic convertion to a char yet it will make it a one byte length

Comment: @A.B.Cade, I see now that I wasn't clear about specifying the conversion of the VARCHAR2(8) string representation into a RAW(1) binary representation. (I guess I thought that was implied by the OP reference to storing "in binary format, it would require 1000/8 bytes of storage."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps, but you can usea NUMBER datatype and [bin_to_num](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions013.htm#i1002025) function:

```
create table test_bin(num_val number, var_val varchar2(1000));

insert into test_bin values(bin_to_num(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0), '10101010');

select dump(num_val, 17) n, dump(var_val, 17) v from test_bin;

n                     |   v
---------------------------------------------------
Typ=2 Len=3 c2,^B,G   |   Typ=1 Len=8 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0
```

As you can see, it's sorter - instead of 8 bytes you have only 3, but it's still not one byte

**UPDATE**
Found a way to have it in one byte:
You can use the `chr` function

```
select dump(chr(bin_to_num(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))) c from dual;

n                   
--------------------
Typ=1 Len=1 170
```

So, you can keep using varchar2 but just convert every 8 bits to a char

Comment: Thanks A.B.Cade... this was what i thought as well, just my solution was decoding 8/16 length bin data to letters my self.

Comment: Just one more question to this:   
select length('a'||chr(254)||'a') from dual
is there an explanation for this? as some of my strings i want to convert to char is 11111101 or 11111110 (and damn how to add br as in ff 2 white space don't work)

Comment: ascii table is only up to 127, so will have to use 7 bits, so at least a compresion by 7

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your questions: use the `dump` functio- The length of chr(254) is 1 byte (as expected). I think you can still use the 8 bit, because chr(0) != chr(128) (BTW chr(0) = chr(256)) (check it with `select dump(chr(0)), dump(chr(128)), dump(chr(256)) from dual`)

Comment: I must say that I'm not really sure how you're going to use the data stored like this. Nor do I see a good way to transform huge amount of data to it. Isn't it better to zip the data and insert it as zipped instead ?

Comment: Converting to/from CHAR datatype introduces issues with characterset translation, is every combination of 8-bits a valid character? Is the mapping complete? Will roundtrip conversion to and from CHAR preserve the original value in ALL cases?

Comment: @spencer7593, You're right but then, you can always store it in a raw data type. The main thing is having 8 characters of 0,1 as 1 byte and not 64. As said in my previous comment - this is what OP requested - I don't know how he's going to work with it, how will he query this data...

Comment: I think the `RAW` datatype is the answer to the OP's question. I was addressing the update to your answer, suggesting the `chr(bin_to_num( ))` could be problematic due to potential characterset conversions. The way to avoid the characterset issues is to AVOID character datatype and use RAW instead.

Comment: @spencer7593, no, the `chr(bin_to_num( ))` is the only way (I found) otherwise, it'll still be a byte for every digit 1,0. By inserting the result of the chr into a raw you will not be reading it as strings anymore but as bytes (it will still be 0,1 and not the translation to char). So, just using a raw is not an answer for OP (and I do admit that my answer may meat requirements but can't be recommended)

Comment: @A.B.Cade - from oracle ascii table all elements from 127 are empty, so this encoding of 8 bit if value is above 127 gives nothing, and in the encoded text i would have nothing. As i wrote select dump('a'||chr(254)||'a') from dual gives 2 bytes, skipping the chr(254)

Answer (score 9):

Use the [RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i46018) datatype if you want to store binary data up to 4000 bytes. The data will be stored as a string of bytes without character set conversion.

Use the [`UTL_RAW`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71350) package to perform operations on `RAWs`.

The LONG RAW datatype is deprecated, you should switch to [BLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref200) when you need to manipulate data with more than 4000 bytes.

Comment: I've used `RAW` datatype to store and process 4-byte and 16-byte (32-bit and 128-bit) binary values. The `RAWTOHEX` and `HEXTORAW` functions are convenient for displaying and updating the RAW values from an interactive client (such as TOAD) where it's much easier to work with strings. I will note that the majority of retrieving and maintaining the stored RAW values was done with PL/SQL. The big advantages of RAW is that characterset translation is not an issue, and 8 logical bits is represented in 1-byte of storage.

Answer (score 7):

See Vincent Malgrat's answer: if you want to store and process binary data in Oracle, then the `RAW` datatype is the way to go.

(As alegen's answer alludes to, if your intent is to store and retrieve images, video, audio or compressed data which doesn't need to be "processed" in the database, but you are just "storing" it and "retrieving" it, then the `BLOB` datatype may be more appropriate;

(NOTE: The RAW datatype is limited to 4000 bytes, the BLOB datatype is not. For peformance reasons, I would prefer to use RAW for values that are much shorter (say, 200 bytes or less), where I need to regularly access the values. For much longer values, where a lot of queries did not reference the binary data, I would tend to favor `BLOB`.  (It's all due to the differences in the way that `RAW` and `BLOB` are stored internally: inline storage vs. separate blocks, split rows, number of rows that fit in a block, etc.)

For the particular problem you describe, from the information you've provided, then `RAW` sounds like the way to go.  You specify that you have sequences of 1000 bits, but it's not at all clear whether that's a constant, or a maximum length, or whether you've broken up longer strings of binary data into more manageable chunks that will fit into columns. (If you are really working with a single, huge chunk of binary data, you really want to avoid "chopping" it up into a bunch of little pieces, and storing each piece on a separate row.  It's going to be much more efficient to store it all together as a single BLOB, and work with it as a simple stream.

All of that is really going to inform your decision on whether to use BLOB or RAW.

---

That aside, on to your question about converting from VARCHAR2 representation of ones and zeros (e.g. '00101010', with each "bit" of real information stored as a separate character, into a more efficiently stored binary representation, with each "8-bits" of real information requiring one byte of storage...

The Oracle `RAW` datatype will get you 8-bits stored into a single byte. That is, a RAW(125) would store the equivalent of your VARCHAR2(1000), which would save you 875 bytes per row (for a SBCS, more than twice that if you're using a DBCS). This will significantly reduce storage requirements, get you more rows in a block, and allow for the possibility of better performance.

To convert the data currently stored as `VARCHAR2` as a string of ones and zeros, I don't know of any built in function that does that. But it's fairly straightforward to roll your own function to convert the binary string representation to hex string representation. After that, you can use the builtin `HEXTORAW` function to convert to `RAW`.

Here's an example that can be used as a starting point.

(NOTE: this function is just an example, it doesn't effectively handle cases when the length of the input string is not a multiple of 8 characters. Also, it's behavior with string values containing characters other than '1' or '0' may not be appropriate (as it's written, it treats any character other than a '0' as if it were a '1'. But, it's good enough as a starting point).

```
create or replace function binstr_to_hexstr
( as_binstr in varchar2 ) return varchar2
is
  li_n binary_integer default 0;
  ls_hexstr varchar2(16) default '0123456789ABCDEF';
  ls_return varchar2(2000) default '';
begin
  if ( as_binstr is null ) then
    return null;
  end if;
  ls_return := '';
  li_n := 0;
  for i in 1 .. length(as_binstr) loop
    li_n := li_n*2 + abs(instr('01',substr(as_binstr,i,1))-1);
    if mod(i,4) = 0 then
      ls_return := ls_return || substr(ls_hexstr,li_n+1,1);
      li_n := 0;
    end if;
  end loop;
return ls_return;
end;
/

SELECT binstr_to_hexstr('00101010') AS hexstr FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT binstr_to_hexstr('00x0 010') FROM DUAL;

HEXSTR                                                                             
------
2A
2A
```

NOTE: This function returns an expected result (a matching hex representation) ONLY when the length of the input string is an even multiple of 8 (i.e. `MOD(length(as_binstr),8) = 0`). Otherwise, the function "loses" trailing bits and/or returns an odd number of hex digits. (The function can be modified to throw an exception when the length of the input argument is not a multiple of 8.)

The `HEXTORAW` and `RAWTOHEX` functions are useful when working with `RAW` data using a client application, such as TOAD, SQL Developer or SQL*Plus. (The `HEXTORAW` function is what we'd use to convert the output from the `binstr_to_hexstr` function to RAW.) As an example:

```
create or replace function binstr_to_raw
( as_binstr in varchar2 ) return raw
is
begin
  return hextoraw(binstr_to_hexstr(as_binstr));
end;
/
```

As Vincent Malgrat pointed out in his answer, Oracle provides a couple of packages (e.g. `UTL_RAW` and `UTL_ENCODE`) which are useful in working with RAW data.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_raw.htm

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use the `BLOB` (Binary Large OBject) type. [Link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/BLOB) to example on how it is used.

Comment: Hi, blob is ok, however will it take 8 bits and store it as 1 byte?
What about binary operations?

Comment: @SauliusS: of course 8bit will make a byte. Do you want a different number of bits for a byte?

Comment: Horse, the question is in blob:='10101010' will i have size in db of 1 byte or 8 bytes? as vsize for blob doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

As of today and I worked with this on 10 and 11g, I think the answer needs an update. The built-in datatype for these sort of data is `RAW` (binary data that can be manipulated far easier than `BLOB` in PL/SQL).

As the name suggests, the `RAW` datatype is the raw binary format and is stored as such (except for the length bytes at the first block), hence the best storage space for this line. `RAW` datatypes can be manipulated using `SYS.UTL_RAW` package. It can be casted to almost any datatype (if storage scheme matches. For instance `b1101` is not the `NUMBER` 13, but it is `PL_INTEGER` 13 and the `VARCHAR2` equivalant of `CHR(13)`.

Also, easier to do rather than casting using `UTL_RAW`, the `HEXTORAW` and `RAWTOHEX` functions cast the data back and forth to `RAW` from hexadecimal representation of data in `VARCHAR2`. For example, the `HEXTORAW('d')` or `HEXTORAW('D')` both result in a `RAW` value of `b00001101`; as you see, extra zeros are padded to the left to form a byte since the basic block of a `RAW` is a byte. The data itself act as little-endian (meaning the least significant byte resides on the right-most byte of the data) during conversions to `VARCHAR2` and other streams, but in casting to complex datatypes like `NUMBER` it only copies the memory over, with padding zeros to the left if nessecary.