# The best way for storing hash in database

Tags: sql, oracle, mariadb

I need to find out the best way from performance and storage point of view for storing the hash, for example, MD5. The current database is MariaDB in the future it could be Oracle. The table will contain hundreds of millions or billions record and each record should include one hash value, that could be used for the search. At this time for storing the hash I use varchar(32), but I think this type is not optimal. I also think about type like binary, char, also as I understand for stable sizes, like in hash, is better to used char instead of varchar and binary instead of varbinary. Also, I think about converting the hash to digits, will it be better?
So what is the best way of storing the hash in Database?

Comment: The result of a hash calculation is a binary value, so it should be stored as a binary value. Converting to a hex-string will double it's storage size and converting to digits increases the size even more.

Comment: Why are you using a hash? What is the source of the hash? How is the hash used?

Comment: what's wrong with VARCHAR2 datatype? It is perfectly fits for your needs. But I'd increase length probably to be able to generate more unique hash values. Btw if hash is build on 1 single column you probably don't need to calc and store it for search but use hash partitioning instead.

Comment: At this time I use MD5 but probably it will be changed to SHA256, the source of the hash it is data in other field insight rows. Hash will be used for public identification and prove correctness(that data is not compromised). At this time varchar is normal, but in case if the table will include several hundred million of rows and each row will include this hash for identification it could be slow.

Comment: It could be slow but not because of VARHCAR. It will have same performance as NUMBER or RAW.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is *each datatype should be stored in the native format* supported by the RDBMS.

This is for **Oracle `RAW(16)`** for the MD5 hash code.

You see this analogy - some have decided to store `DATE` columns using VARCHAR format. You get
a *database independence* but you can't use any function provided for `DATE`columns by your  `RDBMS`.

Anyway you should carefully consider why use a HASH column in a database.

If it is a substitute to quickly recognise a **change of row columns**, it could save you a lot of coding and processing.

To use a **hash code as a key**, try to find at least one reason, that you will profit from a HASH key, compared with a use of a sequence generated key.

Be carefull not to use HASH as a key only because this is recomended from some source before you see in your own imlementation the  described positive effect.

Comment: *at least one reason, that you will profit from a HASH key*: A hash always returns the same value, while a sequence depends on the order of inserts. I'm not advocating DataVault 2.0, but being able to load parent/child tables independently and getting the same key on different systems is really nice.

Comment: I will not use HASH as a key, it is just an identificator that could be used and could guarantee the correctness of data.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL/MariaDB:  `BINARY(16)`.  It occupies 16 bytes, and is sufficient for MD5.  Clearly you need an `INDEX` on the column.

But let me point out a design flaw in using hashes...

If you have a billion rows, but cannot cache more than a fraction of them, then any lookup is very likely to require a disk hit.  This is because of the randomness of MD5 (or UUID or ...).  The in-RAM cache (InnoDB's buffer pool, in the case of MySQL/MariaDB) is unlikely to have the block containing the next value you need.

Do the math.  How fast can a disk block (that is not cached) be read?  A little bit of arithmetic on that gives you how few reads/second you can perform.  A spinning drive: 10ms --> 100 reads/sec.  Multi-threading will not help.  RAID striping will help, some.

Similarly, `INSERTing` is limited to about the same amount.  Early in inserting a billion rows, things will be fast due to caching; later it will slow down to 100 rows/sec.  Inserting a billion rows will take months.

`PARTITIONing` will *not* improve performance.

You may need code (either in SQL or your app) to convert between whatever the function delivers and `BINARY` (which is similar to `BLOB`).

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, use [the `RAW` data type for binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11248178/1509264) up to 4000 bytes and `BLOB` for larger values.

If your hash function generates a number then you can use the [`UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_NUMBER` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_raw.htm#BABBCAEG) to convert it to a `RAW` data type.